# The email address field is incorrect and I'm not sure how to correct it

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

The following piece of code determines the OU of the local computer and should give the email address of the IT administrator of the OU. I want to use the email address in another piece of code but the returned output shows the email field as the OU field. I added last line to see what I was getting as the output. How would I change the code to correct this?

```
 # This section finds the OU of the local computer
$rootDse = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE")
$Domain = $rootDse.DefaultNamingContext
$root = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$Domain")
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($root)
$searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(name=$ComputerName))"
[System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult]$result = $searcher.FindOne()
$dn = $result.Properties["distinguishedName"]
$ouResult = $dn.Substring($ComputerName.Length + 4)

$email = $ouResult 
 Switch ($Email)
{ 
'OU=a,OU=Euro,OU=NB,OU=xxComputers,DC=xxx,DC=com' { 'test.test1@domain.com' }
'OU=a,OU=Euro,OU=NB,OU=xxComputers,DC=xxx,DC=com' { 'test.test1@domain.com' }
'OU=b,OU=Euro,OU=NB,OU=xxComputers,DC=xxx,DC=com' { 'test.test2@domain.com' }
'OU=c,OU=Euro,OU=NB,OU=xxComputers,DC=xxx,DC=com' { 'test.test3@domain.com' }
'OU=d,OU=Euro,OU=NB,OU=xxComputers,DC=xxx,DC=com' { 'test.test4@domain.com' }
'OU=e,OU=Euro,OU=NB,OU=xxComputers,DC=xxx,DC=com' { 'test.test5@domain.com' }
'OU=f,OU=Euro,OU=NB,OU=xxComputers,DC=xxx,DC=com' { 'test.test6@domain.com' } 
 Default { 'Unable to determine $Email' }
}
New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Name" = $ComputerName; "OU" = $ouResult; "Email" = $email}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I am missing something else here but you are not assigning the value of your email address merely sending it as output. You should do something like this:

```
# Remove this line > $email = $ouResult 
Switch ($ouResult)
{ 
    'OU=a,OU=Euro,OU=NB,OU=xxComputers,DC=xxx,DC=com' { $email = 'test.test1@domain.com' }
    'OU=a,OU=Euro,OU=NB,OU=xxComputers,DC=xxx,DC=com' { $email = 'test.test1@domain.com' }
    # ... trucated
    'OU=f,OU=Euro,OU=NB,OU=xxComputers,DC=xxx,DC=com' { $email = 'test.test6@domain.com' } 
     Default { '$ouResult not mapped to email address' }
}
```

Also, since most of the query is the same and its just the first OU that is different you could use the `-wildcard` switch for `switch`

```
Switch -Wildcard ($ouResult)
{ 
    'OU=a,*' { $email = 'test.test1@domain.com' }
    'OU=a,*' { $email = 'test.test1@domain.com' }
    # ... trucated
    'OU=f,*' { $email = 'test.test6@domain.com' } 
     Default { '$ouResult not mapped to email address' }
}
```

Comment: Good to know. Consider marking this as the answer using the green check mark then to the left of this answer